# How do I compare two files containing several md5 checksums to determine changed files?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, md5sum

I have two files `MD1` and `MD2`.

`MD1` contains md5sums:

```
5f31caf675f2542a971582442a6625f6  /root/md5filescreator/hash1.txt
4efe4ba4ba9fd45a29a57893906dcd30  /root/md5filescreator/hash2.txt
1364cdba38ec62d7b711319ff60dea01  /root/md5filescreator/hash3.txt
```

where `hash1`, `hash2` and `hash3` are three files present in folder `md5filescreator`.

Similarly `MD2` contains:

```
163559001ec29c4bbbbe96344373760a  /root/md5filescreators/hash1.txt
4efe4ba4ba9fd45a29a57893906dcd30  /root/md5filescreators/hash2.txt
1364cdba38ec62d7b711319ff60dea01  /root/md5filescreators/hash3.txt
```

where these files are in folder `md5filescreators`.

I want to compare the checksums in `md5filescreator` with the corresponding file's checksum in `md5filecreators`.

The shell script should return **OK** for files with same checksums and **FALSE** for those which are not, along with the file names.

Can this be done using `md5sum --check` (since it normally checks for any changes in only 1 MD5 file)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *I want to know if this can be done using `md5sum --check`?* (since it normally checks for any changes in only 1 MD5 file).

No, it can't.

`md5sum --check` is meant to read the path to each file in the second column of the input files and check their MD5 checksum agains the checksum reported on the first column; if you want to directly compare the checksums in the two files, you'll have to compare the text files.

Using `paste` + AWK you could do:

```bsh
paste file1 file2 | awk '{x = $1 == $3 ? "OK" : "FALSE"; print $2" "x}'
```

- `paste file1 file2`: joins line N of `file1` on line N of `file2`;
- `awk '{x = $1 == $3 ? "OK" : "FALSE"; print $2" "x}'`: if the first field is equal to the third field (i.e. the MD5 sums match), assigns "OK" to `x`, otherwise assigns "FALSE" to `x` and prints the second field (i.e. the filename) followed by the value of `x`.

```
% cat file1
5f31caf675f2542a971582442a6625f6 /root/md5filescreator/hash1.txt
4efe4ba4ba9fd45a29a57893906dcd30 /root/md5filescreator/hash2.txt
1364cdba38ec62d7b711319ff60dea01 /root/md5filescreator/hash3.txt
% cat file2
163559001ec29c4bbbbe96344373760a /root/md5filescreators/hash1.txt
4efe4ba4ba9fd45a29a57893906dcd30 /root/md5filescreators/hash2.txt
1364cdba38ec62d7b711319ff60dea01 /root/md5filescreators/hash3.txt
% paste file1 file2 | awk '{x = $1 == $3 ? "OK" : "FALSE"; print $2" "x}'
/root/md5filescreator/hash1.txt FALSE
/root/md5filescreator/hash2.txt OK
/root/md5filescreator/hash3.txt OK
```

Comment: Nice solution,however if I have some extra lines in file 2
163559001ec29c4bbbbe96344373760a/root/md5filescreators/hash1.txt
4efe4ba4ba9fd45a29a57893906dcd30 /root/md5filescreators/hash2.txt
ab6d1089231ec655831db196bef4a729  /root/md5filescreator/xyz.txt
1364cdba38ec62d7b711319ff60dea01 /root/md5filescreators/hash3.txt
In that case hash3 will be compared with xyz and not hash3. How to approach in that case ,just curious?(the real number of files is >10^9 ,so sorting may not be beneficial perhaps)

Comment: I don't understand how this will work ,NF=4 means 4 fields right?

Comment: @swapedoc Nevermind, I missundertood what you were saying. Right now only sorting is occurring to me. For example `paste <(sort -k 2.1 file1) <(sort -k 2.1 file2) | awk 'NF == 4 && $1 == $3 {print $2": OK"; next} {print $2": FALSE"}'` should work... I don't think there's a way other than sorting though. And yes, `NF == 4` is an additional condition needed in order to print `: OK` (i.e. if there are less than 4 fields the file is missing either in `file1` or `file2`).

Comment: Actually I want to compare files with same names located in different folders.The reason for same names are files in folder 1 go through a device and the output is stored in folder 2 .To check the integrity I generate 2 checksum files MD1 and MD2 for all the files in folder 1 and folder 2 respectively. Since these files have same data they should match and have same name.But output file also contains some more files.That is the trouble. :(

Comment: @swapedoc Have you tried `paste <(sort -k 2.1 file1) <(sort -k 2.1 file2) | awk 'NF == 4 && $1 == $3 {print $2": OK"; next} {print $2": FALSE"}'`? How does it perform? Another way would be `grep`ping (or matching with AWK) each single file listed in `file1` in `file2`, it should be less expensive than sorting both files.

Comment: I will let you know tomorrow about the performance .Anyways thanks for the clever answer :)

Comment: @swapedoc No problem. Let me know, I'm curious. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36981/discussion-between-swapedoc-and-kos).

Comment: Well the new script also failed

Comment: @swapedoc How exactly? (You can join the chat and ping me there).

Comment: I have pinged you in chat

Answer (score 4):

A simple way of checking this would be to see which lines are *not* duplicated across both files:

```
sort file1 file2 | uniq --unique
```

[`uniq --unique` prints those lines which haven't appeared again](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/210530/70524). Accordingly, those files whose hashes match will have duplicated lines, and won't appear in the output. To simply test if any output is produced, use `grep`:

```
sort file1 file2 | uniq --unique | grep -q .
```

In this case, since the directories are different, a bit more processing is needed:

```
awk -F/ '{print $1, $NF}' | sort | uniq --unique | awk '!a[$2]++{print $2}'
```

Or, entirely in awk:

```
awk -F/ 'FNR == NR {hash[$NF] = $1; next} hash[$NF] != $1 {print $NF}'
```

In both cases, you get just the filenames whose hashes differ.